# PowerShell: string to datetime, but in European format

Tags: powershell

I can create a `DateTime` Object from a string like this:

`[datetime]"10.12.2018"`

Problem is, it will always take American DateTime

```
PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts\Functions> [datetime]"10.12.2018"

Freitag, 12. Oktober 2018 00:00:00
```

Can I somehow tell PowerShell that I'm in Europe and it should create European datetime objects?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `DateTime.Parse()` with a `CultureInfo` instance:

```
$dateString = '10.12.2018'

# DateTime.Parse accepts an IFormatProvider - and CultureInfo implements IFormatProvider!
# Let's take French
$frenchCulture = [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('fr-FR')

# Pass the format provider as the second argument
[datetime]::Parse($dateString, $frenchCulture)
```